# Math.random() and "hexChars" PHP equivalents

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to convert a JavaScript to php but I am not sure how to convert `Math.random()` and `hexChars` method in below JavaScript function to PHP, thanks for any help

**JavaScript function:**

```
    function generateId(){
        var a=[],b;
        a[8]=a[13]=a[18]=a[23]="-";
        a[14]="4";

        for(i=0;i<36;i++)
        if(!a[i]){
            b=0|Math.random()*16;
            a[i]=hexChars[i==19?b&3|8:b]
        }
        return a.join("")       
    }
```

**PHP function** I converted so far:

```
function generateId(){
    $a = array();
    $a[8]=$a[13]=$a[18]=$a[23]="-";
    $a[14]="4";
    for($i=0;$i<36;$i++){
        if(!$a[$i]){
        // not sure what to do here 
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: 
it will create a string like this: 902EA4DD-5445-4435-93F2-2A5203818255

Comment: You can use php's [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function

Comment: `hexChars` is not a function but an array.

Comment: Where is the definition of `hexChars`?

Comment: Any reasons for the downvotes?

Comment: @eisberg "no research effort", perhaps? Just guessing.

Comment: eisberg I am not sure either why there are downvotes, i tried to explain every bit but i guess next time i should also post my own answer.

Comment: @Dshah Updated working code here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/je3-6zc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b = 0|Math.random()*16;
```

returns a random integer from 0 to 15. The equivalent PHP code is

```
$b = rand(0,15);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

---

```
a[i]=hexChars[i==19?b&3|8:b]
```

hexChars is an array. In PHP, you can use the array notation to index a character from a string:

```
$hexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF"
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I am not much familiar with JavaScript and your reply helped.

Answer (score 2):

#### I assume that the `hexChars` is an array of Hex Characters.

```
<?php
    function generateId(){
        $hexChars = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
        $a = array();
        $a[8] = $a[13] = $a[18] = $a[23] = "-";
        $a[14] = "4";
        for ($i=0; $i < 36; $i++)
            if (!isset($a[$i]))
                $a[$i] = $hexChars[mt_rand(0,15)];
        ksort($a);
        return implode($a);
    }
    echo generateId();
?>
```

#### Demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/je3-6zc

Comment: Where's `F`? :) And you should probably use `mt_rand(0, 15)`

Comment: `mt_rand(0, 1) * 16` is wrong. `mt_rand` returns an integer in the specified range.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Where is `F`? :-)

Comment: Instead of `ksort()` you can also pre-populate with `$a = array_fill(0, 36, null);`

Answer (score 2):

I would redo the whole thing:

```
function generateId() {
    $id = md5(mt_rand());
    return substr($id, 0, 8) . '-' . substr($id, 9, 4) . '-' 
        . substr($id, 13, 4) . '-' . substr($id, 17, 4) . '-'
        . substr($id, 21, 4) . '-' . substr($id, 25);
}
```

[You can play around](http://codepad.org/G8kNedyf) with the data you use for your `md5()` function, if you need more entropy, but this should get you started.